# Change Status from Pending to Approved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Hello here i have a haml index.

```
%h1 Requests
%table
%thead
  %tr
    %th Request Template
    %th User
    %th Sent At
    %th Status
%tbody
  - @requests.each do |request|
    %tr
      %td= link_to request.request_template_id, admin_request_template(requests.request_template_id)
      %td= request.user_id
      %td= request.request_sent_at
      %td= request.status
```

If you see on the last line it says request.status. Right now it displays the status which is set to pending as default using an after_save in the Request Model.

**I will like the user to click on the status and change it to Approved. How do i to do this?** I have an array that can display the statuses. I also have a status column for the Requests table.

Please see my Request Model below.

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :request_template
  belongs_to :user

  has_many   :request_answers, autosave: true

  validates :request_template, :user, presence: true

  after_create :send_notification, :status_pending

  STATUSES= %w[pending approved]

  def send_notification
    RequestMailer.delay.new_request_admin_notification(id)
    request_notification_sent_date!
  end

  def request_notification_sent_date!
    update_attribute :request_sent_at, Time.current
  end

  def pending!
    update_attribute :status, "pending"
  end

  def approved!
    update_attribute :status, "approved"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next to your `request.status` you can have a link to the update action:

`link_to 'Approve', request_path(request, request: {status: 'approved'}), method: put`.

Your `RequestsController` should be set up to accept the `status` params if you are using strong parameters

PS: Not relevant to the question, but if you set the default value of your `status` column to `pending`, then you wouldn't need the `after_create` callback to set the status.